# @material ui/core npm alias failed

Tags: installation

I am currently using @ material ui/core v1.5 version in my project. Now I want to introduce v4 version and think of using aliases. I use the command: npm install mui-v4@npm : @ material ui/ core@4 After execution, the original v1.5 version was overwritten, and the content corresponding to mui-v4 is undefined@0.0.0

I would like to know the method to enable multiple versions of mui to be used in the same project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEIVA.png)

I would like to know the method to enable multiple versions of mui to be used in the same project